# What is meant by an eligible purchase on a cash back card

Tags: credit-card

I am trying to decide on a credit card for travel purposes and i came to [MBNA](http://www.mbna.ca/credit-cards/overview/rewards/mbna-rewards/index.jsp)

At this link, the word 'eligible purchases' keep cropping up, so I was wondering where I can find a list of eligible purchases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What "eligible purchases" means is defined by the credit card agreement.  In the info on those cards, I see this statement:

> Complete terms and conditions describing eligibility of your rewards program, MBNA Dollar Points accrual and redemption, and other important conditions, limitations and restrictions will be sent after your account is opened.

Thus it appears you cannot know exactly what will be eligible until after you open the account.  You could try calling the company and asking.